# Hide column in DataGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid, sharepoint-2007, .net-2.0

I am making a SharePoint web part in which I am using System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGrid control. Think of web part as some component you develop in Net.

Its AutoGenerateColumns property is set to TRUE.

I am trying to hide a column at run time. I have written the following code on this controls ItemCreated event but it only works if I e.Item.Cells[0] and it doesn't work for any other value for e.g. e.Item.Cells[1] and e.Item.Cells[6].

There are 9 columns in my DataGrid control.

**Code**

```
protected void grd1_ItemCreated(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
{
      e.Item.Cells[0].Visible = false; //works fine
      e.Item.Cells[1].Visible = false; //gives error
      e.Item.Cells[2].Visible = false; //gives error
}
```

**Error**

```
Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: index 

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
```

How to hide a particular column?

Comment: i posted answer try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this

```
 <asp:DataGrid ID="dgShowTiming"
              runat="server" OnItemCreated="dgShowTiming_OnItemCreated"
              AutoGenerateColumns="false">


protected void dgShowTiming_OnItemCreated(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
    {
        MyDataGrid.Columns[0].Visible = false;
            //  0=represents your first column

    }
```

You can make `visible= true,false` by using `Columns[index]` and its settting index

Comment: I want to keep AutoGenerateColumns to true otherwise I may have to make many changes in code.